# C++ throwing exception

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I have class

```
template <class T>
class Box {
    public:
        Box() : size(2), count(0) {
            arr = new T[size];
        }
        void add(T);
        T operator[](int);
    private:
        int size;
        int count;
        T * arr;
};
```

operator[ ] function

```
template <class T>
T Box<T>::operator[](int index) {
    if (index >= count)
        throw "Index out of bounds";
    return arr[index];
}
```

In main function, I first add one element to Box using `add` function. Then I tried to get it by `box[0]` and it works fine. I want the code throwing an exception when I tried to do `box[1]` since there is no 2nd element. But instead of throwing an exception, it gives me this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7701DAD8 in Project24.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: char at memory location 0x0018F8A8.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I do have an exception handler. Why am I getting this error?

**EDIT:** I opened a new project, copied all files and changed the function `operator[]` as

```
template <class T>
T Box<T>::operator[](size_t index) {
    string s("Index out of bounds");
    if (index >= count)
        throw s;
    return arr[index];
}
```

It works now.

Comment: You should create complete, minimal, and verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Might the problem be that you're throwing a const char * and that it is not really safe in terms of memory? Try to throw a std::string instead

Comment: Are you running a debug session in the VS debugger?

Comment: Yes, I deleted all the body part of `operator[]` function and the error still occurs.

Comment: I check with the VS debugger and `operator[]` is called

Comment: That's not an error, it's the message you get when you have enabled breaking when an exception is thrown (that is, before it gets propagated). You can press Continue, as the message suggests, and your handler will catch it.

Comment: @iammilind: This question is - by far - not a duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 2):

This *error* is generally displayed by VS whenever a C++ exception is thrown and the program is executed in debug mode. You normally have a button *Continue* to allow the program to continue and to reach the handler.

BTW, the usage in C++ is to only throw classes derived from `std::exception`. It is by no way required but is considered as a good practice.